# Why does waitForKeyElements() only trigger once despite later changes?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

For several years I've used the [`waitForKeyElements()`](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) function to track changes in webpages from a userscript. However, sometimes I've found it doesn't trigger as expected and have worked around out. I've run into another example of this problem, and so am now trying to figure out what the problem is. The following is the barest example I can create.

Given a simple HTML page that looks like this:

```
<span class="e1">blah</span>
```

And some Javascript:

```
// function defined here https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891
waitForKeyElements('.e1', handle_e1, false);

function handle_e1(node) {
    console.log(node.text());
    alert(node.text());
}

setInterval(function() {
    $('.e1').text("updated: "+Math.random());
}, 5000);
```

I would expect this code to trigger an `alert()` and a `console.log()` every 5 seconds. However, it only triggers once. Any ideas?

Here's [a codepen that demonstrates this](http://codepen.io/bengrosser/pen/MygjrW?editors=1010).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design and default, `waitForKeyElements` processes a node just once.  To tell it to keep checking, **return `true` from the callback function.**
You'll also want to compare the string (or whatever) to see if it has changed.

So, in this case, `handle_e1()`  would be something like:

```
function handle_e1 (jNode) {
    var newTxt  = jNode.text ();
    if (typeof this.lastTxt === "undefined"  ||  this.lastTxt !== newTxt) {
        console.log (newTxt);
        this.lastTxt = newTxt;
    }
    return true;    // Allow repeat firings for this node.
}
```

---

---

With the constant string comparisons though, performance *might* be an issue if you have a lot of this on one page. In that scenario, switching to a `MutationObserver` approach might be best.

Comment: Thank you. So would it be accurate to say that, without what you describe above, that waitForKeyElements() is meant to detect objects that are dynamically *added* to the page as opposed to (also) tracking when an object *changes* on a page?

Comment: It was originally meant more for added elements, yes. But it can do both as shown.  I only mentioned MutationObserver as lots of string comparisons like that can theoretically slow down the page if you do enough of them (probably a few thousand elements under scan).  In practice this was only an issue for me once out of many hundreds of applications.  MutationObserver is now fairly stable (didn't exist when WFKE was born) and can be more elegant for tracking changes.